# Repeating vbs script with multiple urls

Tags: vbscript

I need to run this script automatically, but with different urls, specified in the urllist.txt file.

```
Dim objWshShell,IE,searchStr

Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With IE
  .Visible = True
  .Navigate "url.com"

  Do While .Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
  Loop

set objButtons = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
for each objButton in objButtons
    strText = objButton.innerhtml

    if InStr(strText,"rtes") > 0 then
    'msgbox strText
objButton.click
        exit for
        end if
next
end with
ie.quit
```

urllist.txt content:

url1.com
url2.com
...

Can you please help?

Comment: Read the text file line by line using a filesystem object. For each line, execute the code you have pasted.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can read urls from urllist.txt. 
How can I navigate my script to these urls and let the script do the job?
I added this at the top of vbscript:

filename = "urllist.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  WScript.Echo f.ReadLine
Loop

f.Close

Comment: Just posted in the answer. Just store your url file's path in the variable and run the code.

Comment: Also make sure that there is one URL per line in the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the text file, read it line by line using the **readline** method and for each line run your code.

Code:

```
Dim IE,searchStr, objFso, objFile, strFilePath
strFilePath = "store the file's path in this variable"   'store the path here
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.visible=True
Set objFso = createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strFilePath,1)
While Not objFile.AtEndOfStream
    IE.Navigate trim(objFile.Readline)
    Do While IE.Busy
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop
    set objButtons = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    for each objButton in objButtons
        strText = objButton.innerhtml
        if InStr(1,strText,"rtes") > 0 then
            'msgbox strText
             objButton.click
             exit for
        end if
    next
Wend
IE.Quit
objFile.Close
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFso = Nothing
Set IE = Nothing
```

Comment: A few urls runs perfect, but after a while it stops. If I close IE, 800A01CE error code comes with VBScript runtime error message.
Do I need to set sleep time somewhere?

Comment: Can you share your text file's URLs here, by editing your question?. Will try to run on my side.

Comment: Ia am trying in facebook groups to press buttons for set up alerting in each group. It seems, that facebook needs some time to enable the next action. I increased sleep to 20000. Now it works again.